# Error due to imageview in android 3.1.2 while generating signed apk

Tags: android

I can able to install debug apk or build apk in mobile 
below is the xml, i am using only drawable and not like drawable-21 or 24 like that so please have look in my xml file i am using png images only...................................................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/u_text_logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_friend"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="223dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/web_hi_res"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.578" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but when i generate signed apk then  i getting error crash like this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.xxx.xx/xxx.xxx.xx.SplasScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.ag.b(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.r.setContentView(Unknown Source)
    at hemanth.com.vtuquestionpaper2017.SplasScreen.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6357)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:786)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.at.d()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageDrawable(Unknown Source)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:154)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.av.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.ag.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.ag.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: build apk fine but signed apk is getting crash gradle is 3.1.0

Comment: Have a look on updated answer.

Comment: can you update the gradle 3.1.2 and check may android editor issues some times

Comment: now its working after upgrading to 3.1.2 but now i am getting Theme error in style but still i am able to build apk, any way thx

Comment: @Hemanth SP, what about is plugin for Gradle 3.0.1/Gradle 4.1?

Comment: @AndySander i dont want latest 4,1 gradle for my project

Comment: @Hemanth SP, maybe you're confusing Android plugin for Gradle and Gradle? Try downgrade Android plugin for Gradle version to 3.0.1 in build.gradle file. And Gradle to 4.1 in gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is created in only release build becuase proguard removes some useful classes or method from code.

You can read and understand rules for proguard from [Google dev docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code). or [Basics](https://medium.com/@jonfinerty/beginner-to-proguard-b3327ff3a831)

For now you can add this rule to your proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

Try clean build and make release apk after adding this rule.

Here is proguard-rules.pro located

[image: proguard]

I tell you shortcut too ;)

Remove proguard setting so android will not remove any classes for shrinking code. in your app level `build.gradle` change below

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

to this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
    }
}
```

Then sync and build apk. It should run.

**Update**

Proguard is free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names.

Comment: if i remove the progurd then what is the use to me i need progurad enabled all time

Comment: Updated answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding below line in your **activity's onCreate() method:**

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

Add below attribute to **ImageView in your xml:**

```
app:srcCompact
```

**instead of android:src**.

Comment: This isn't about vector drawables ? or is it ?